# Expected hitting time Ising model

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I was wondering if there is any explicit expression for the expected hitting time from one configuration of the Ising model to another under the heat-bath or Glauber dynamics. In the literature, I can only find bounds on this quantity in the low-temperature regime, but I am interested in an expression that holds for any value of the temperature.